# fetching QueryString in a non Controller class

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I want to fetch a `QueryString` in a non controller class

```
string configType = Request.QueryString["configType"];
```

what namespace should I use?

`using System.Web` doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var valueOfT = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.QueryString["t"];
```

But there have to be active `HttpContext`.

*But I would better suggest to pass the value from your controller class to non-controller class.*